# How to SET a variable value in a function?

Tags: postgresql

I want to change the schema search path in a function, based on parameters given to that function. However, calling this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test(in_schema text)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $fun$
BEGIN
  SET search_path TO in_schema, public;

  RETURN '';
END;
$fun$
```

doesn't work. It sets the search path to `in_schema, public`, instead of what I give in the function.

How can I set the search path inside a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [dynamic sql:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

```
CREATE FUNCTION test(in_schema text)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $fun$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('SET search_path TO %I, public', in_schema);

  RETURN '';
END;
$fun$
```